How to use wget to pull down a web page for offline viewing, but save the html in a different place
I've done the usual research.  I understand that you can use wget to pull down a copy of a web page with something like this:
wget --adjust-extension --span-hosts --convert-links --backup-converted --page-requisites https://example.com/some/page/

However the result of this command looks something like this:
- example.com
  /some
    /page
      - index.html
      - logo.png
      - style.css

- somewhere.ca
  - picture.jpg

- somewherelese.org
  - awesome.ttf

The page.html file I'm looking for lives deep inside that example.com folder, and obviously if I move that file into the "root", the links inside it won't work anymore:
- index.html
- example.com
  /some
    /page
      - logo.png
      - style.css

- somewhere.ca
  - picture.jpg

- somewherelese.org
  - awesome.ttf

This is what I want though: to be able to download a copy of a single page and have the result be called index.html, within it, links to sibling folders.  Is there a way for me to tell wget to do this?  Alternatively, is there a secondary command I can issue to re-address all links so that I can move the index.html into the root and not break anything?
